# How to prove that x $\longrightarrow$ x$_B$ gives a bijective linear map between V and $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

How to prove that **x** $\longrightarrow$ **x**$_B$ gives a bijective linear map between V and $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Given:

Let V and W be vector space and $ A: V \longrightarrow W $ be a linear map.

**x**$_B $ is the column consisting of the coordinates of **x** with respect to B, where **x** $\in$ V can be uniquely written as **x** = $ x_1 $$ $**b**$ _1 $ + ... + $ x_n $$ $**b**$ _n $ and where B is an ordered basis, B = {**b** _1, ..., **b** _n }.

I got this assignment for school and I think I should start proving injectivity and bijectivity, and I know that for a linear map that is bijective that ker(A) = {**0**} and A(V) = W. However, I really don't know how to start with the proof and how to work with **x** $\longrightarrow$ **x**$_B$.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I would advise working with the inverse map, taking $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)^\top \in \Bbb{R}^n$ to $a_1 \mathbf{b}_1 + \ldots + a_n \mathbf{b}_n \in V$. This is much more concrete, and is even defined when $B$ is not a basis. It's only bijective if $B$ is a basis though. If you can argue it's linear and bijective, then so is its inverse.

Comment: @user847970 I want to thank you for your comment! I was thinking about that as well, but I really didn't know how to start that proof. In your exemple you write (a1,…,an)⊤ ∈ Rn  to a1b1 +…+ anbn ∈ V. but can you also use this with (v1,...,vn) and v1b1 etc. or is the small a connected to the transformation A. And how is it still defined when B is not a basis?

Comment: The $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are just arbitrary real numbers, unconnected to any $A$. They're just used to define a linear transformation from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $V$. Even if $B$ is not a basis, we can still map vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ to linear combinations in exactly the same way. It's not hard to prove that $B$ is spanning if and only if the map is surjective, and $B$ is linearly independent if and only if the map is injective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ is a vector space with a ordered basis $B=\{v_{1},v_{2},\ldots,v_{n}\}$, also let
\begin{eqnarray*}
[\cdot]_{B}: (V,F,+,\cdot) &\to & \mathbb{R}^{n}\\
v\mapsto [v]_{B}&=&(\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\ldots,\alpha_{n})
\end{eqnarray*}
where $v=\alpha_{1}v_{1}+\alpha_{2}v_{2}+\cdots \alpha_{n}v_{n}$, so $[\cdot]_{B}$ is a bijection from $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

**Statement:** $[\cdot]_{B}$ is a linear transformation. Indeed, you can prove that

1. $[\alpha v]_{B}=\alpha[v]_{B}$
2. $[v+w]_{B}=[v]_{B}+[w]_{B}$

Now, you know that $$[\cdot]_{B} \quad \text{is bijection} \quad \iff [\cdot]_{B} \quad \text{injective} \quad \wedge \quad [\cdot]_{B} \quad \text{surjective}$$

Now, note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{ker}([v]_{B})=\left\{v \in V: [v]_{B}=\vec{0}_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \right\} \overbrace{\implies}^{solving} \mathbf{ker}([v]_{B})=\vec{0}_{V} \implies [v]_{B} \quad \text{is injective}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Also, you can see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{im}([v]_{B})=\left\{w \in \mathbb{R}^{n}:\exists v \in V: [v]_{B}=w \right\} \overbrace{\implies}^{solving} \mathbf{im}([v]_{B})=\mathbb{R}^{n} \implies [v]_{B} \quad \text{is surjective}.
\end{eqnarray*}

So, $[v]_{B}$ is a bijection from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.